# Saving running apps on logout/poweroff in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu

How can I save the running apps on logout/shutdown so that they are restored when I login/power on? [Restore previous saved session is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WWAx.png) but it still does not work. This was working fine in Kubuntu 22.04.1 on a different machine(upgraded from 20.04 full install) but is not working in my current Kubuntu 22.04.1 minimal installation. Is it not working because this is a minimal install? If so, what package/configuration is needed to enable this save session to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is helpful but this is my experience.  It doesn't matter what I choose in *System Settings: Startup and Shutdown: Desktop Session: When logging in*, my new sessions are always empty.  This [page](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Desktop_Session) suggests that selecting *Restore manually saved session* should offer a *Save Session* option on logging out (etc.) but that doesn't appear for me.  The crucial change seems to be that, in Kubuntu 20.04 (and previously, as I recall), the first option to *When logging in* was *Restore previous session* -- which would then reopen any KDE apps that were running at the time of leaving -- whereas now the first option is *Restore previous saved session* (which would be okay, if I could save a session :/)